# Manipulating IO from an audio interface

Tags: audio-processing

So this is a relatively complex question I’m sure, as I have no idea what I’m getting myself into here. The gist of the project I would like to undertake is that I want to turn an old AIO PC (computer built into a monitor) into a multi-fx processor. I plan on loading Windows Server onto the machine to reduce the number of background tasks taking up memory and cpu cycles. So as far as the audio side of things, I will have a USB interface plugged into the machine as well as a MIDI controller to send signals to the application to switch effects presets. Now to the questions.

1. Are there any C/C++ libraries that are able to get an input signal from an audio interface and feed a modified signal to the output of the audio interface? I ask about C/C++ because they’re the only languages I assume would be able to achieve a low latency.
2. Are there any C/C++ libraries that are able to read input from a MIDI controller or assign callbacks for when a MIDI controller action occurs?
3. Is there a certain audio interface I should buy for compatibility reasons? Like considering ASIO compatibility, etc.
4. Will there be any complications regarding signal level? My chain will be guitar->audio interface in->effects processor app->audio interface out->amplifier.

Comment: i dunno about a library that you can get, but the older version of this [StringPort](https://www.keithmcmillen.com/labs/stringport-2/) technology was sending audio over the USB.  so somebody has been doing it.

Comment: FX processor ... hmm ... can you add CPU specs ... ?

Comment: It’s an old pentium dual-core.

Comment: OK, that could suite for few effects (not very complex) at once. There are ready to use applications (commercial/freeware) to do what you describe but, if you really want to make your own software then there are good C++ frameworks as like JUCE you would like to check - https://juce.com/ . What comes to audio interface, low latency is needed so ASIO compatibility might be a must (bundled device drivers do the I/O handling so you need just to make it happen in your software).